# Make a switch to copy values between fields in Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, formik

Hi I'm building a form with Formik on NextJS and I'm putting a switch to give the user the possibility to use contact details for invoice.

I have different fields for both contact details and invoice details but I want to add a switch that will copy the contact infos into the invoice details form.

[image]

that's what I'm doing now :

```js
<Formik
                initialValues={{
                    passengers: passengers,
                    contact: contactDetails,
                  invoice: useContactDetails ? {...invoiceDetails, ...contactDetails} : invoiceDetails
                }}
                onSubmit={
                    (values, actions) => {
                       console.log(values)
                    }
                }
            >
                {({errors, touched, isSubmitting}: any) => (
                    <Form>
                        <PassengerItem>
                            <PassengerHeaderContainer>
                                <PassengerHeader>
                                    {(t('flightsCheckout.main.contactDetails'))}
                                </PassengerHeader>
                            </PassengerHeaderContainer>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.firstName')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. John (Given Name)"
                                        name={`contact.firstName`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                                <DottedLinesContainer>
                                    <DottedLines />
                                </DottedLinesContainer>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.lastName')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. Smith (Last Name)"
                                        name={`contact.lastName`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.phoneNumber')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="tel"
                                        placeholder="E.G. +30 645 654 9850"
                                        name={`contact.phoneNumber`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                                <DottedLinesContainer>
                                    <DottedLines />
                                </DottedLinesContainer>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.emailAddress')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="E.G. john.smith@example.com"
                                        name={`contact.emailAddress`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                    {
                                        errors.contactEmail &&
                                        <ErrorText>{errors.contactEmail}</ErrorText>
                                    }
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.country')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput name={`contact.country`} required as="select" style={{background: "none"}}>
                                        <option style={{color: "#ADADAD"}} value="" disabled selected>E.G. United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="spain">Spain</option>
                                        <option value="morocco">Morocco</option>
                                        <option value="romania">Romania</option>
                                    </TextInput>
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                        </PassengerItem>

                        <PassengerItem>
                            <PassengerHeaderContainer>
                                <PassengerHeader>
                                    {(t('flightsCheckout.main.invoiceDetails'))}
                                </PassengerHeader>
                            </PassengerHeaderContainer>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <CustomSwitch
                                    label={t('flightsCheckout.main.sameAsContact')}
                                    state={useContactDetails}
                                    setState={setUseContactDetails}
                                />
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.firstName')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. John (Given Name)"
                                        name={`invoice.firstName`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                                <DottedLinesContainer>
                                    <DottedLines />
                                </DottedLinesContainer>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.lastName')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. Smith (Last Name)"
                                        name={`invoice.lastName`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.phoneNumber')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="tel"
                                        placeholder="E.G. +30 645 654 9850"
                                        name={`invoice.phoneNumber`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                                <DottedLinesContainer>
                                    <DottedLines />
                                </DottedLinesContainer>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.emailAddress')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="E.G. john.smith@example.com"
                                        name={`invoice.emailAddress`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                    {
                                        errors.invoiceEmail &&
                                        <ErrorText>{errors.invoiceEmail}</ErrorText>
                                    }
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.country')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput name={`invoice.country`} required as="select" style={{background: "none"}}>
                                        <option style={{color: "#ADADAD"}} value="" disabled selected>E.G. United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="spain">Spain</option>
                                        <option value="morocco">Morocco</option>
                                        <option value="romania">Romania</option>
                                    </TextInput>
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.address')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. 64 Notley Street"
                                        name={`invoice.address`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                                <DottedLinesContainer>
                                    <DottedLines />
                                </DottedLinesContainer>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.city')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. London"
                                        name={`invoice.city`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputLabel>
                                        {t('flightsCheckout.main.zipCode')}
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <TextInput
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="E.G. 40741"
                                        name={`invoice.zipCode`}
                                        required
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </PassengerItem>
                )}
            </Formik>
```

I tried this but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set `enableReinitialize` to true on Formik in order for it to refresh with the new values. The default is set to false, and since you are changing the initialValues, you need to reinitialize it

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean